# Trying to use Data to create a menu

Tags: java, menu

I’m trying to use Data that I saw from another post [Creating a console menu for user to make a selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059259/creating-a-console-menu-for-user-to-make-a-selection) to create a menu in which the user selects an option. When I go to run my program it throws several errors. 
Maybe I’m not importing it correctly but this is the only method 
I can think of.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Data;
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Please enter 1 if you'd like to guess the computer's number or enter 2 to have the computer guess your number. If 2, please enter a number between 1-100 after you enter 2. ");
Data data = new Data();
    data.menu();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
        double r = (Math.random()*((100-1)+1))+min;

        int win = 0;
        while (win != 1);
        System.out.println("The computer has guessed a number, please make a guess. ");
        int u1 = scanner.nextInt();  
        if (r > u1)
        System.out.println("Too low.");
        else if (r < u1)
        System.out.println("Too high.");
        else if (r == u1){
        System.out.println("You guessed it!!!!!!! Congratulations!!!!!!!!!!");
        int win = win + 1 ;}
        else
        System.out.println();
         break;
        case 2:
        System.out.println("You'd like myself, the computer to guess huh, well be prepared to get destroyed!");
        int un = scanner.nextInt();
        if (un == 36){
        System.out.println("Chandler I told you not to!!!!!!");
        break;}
        else
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Your number is " + un);
          break;


        default:
        System.out.println("You weren't supposed to do that!!!! Stop the program and run it again. Congrats! You broke it! Chandler, if you entered 36, ");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        System.out.print("you've been banned!");
}

}

}
```

Comment: `import java.util.Data;` - Pretty sure this doesn't exist, but, I'd say it wasn't what you'd be looking for anyway.  I'd say the `Data` class was custom class created by the original poster

Comment: Do you know if there is a class that does what I need it to?

Comment: No, you'll have to create it yourself

Comment: Ok thank you I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

All your compiler errors in order.

```
import java.util.Data; // Does not exist, @MadProgrammer is correct, causes error
Data data = new Data(); // Error, Data cannot be resolved as to a type

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // You did not import java.util.Scanner.
// Scanner cannot be resolved to a type.

double r = (Math.random()*((100-1)+1))+min; // min cannot be resolved to a variable
// You didn't define it

System.out.println("The computer has guessed a number, please make a guess. ");
int win = win + 1 ;} // win was a variable that was previously defined. Just change it 
from "int win =" to "win = "

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5); // Did you mean to import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

Also, if you want to "ban" someone from your program, then why not make a .txt file to read from, that helps your program remember if it has been "broken" before.